# How can I limit the plot of $f(x,y)=\rm{cons}t$ to the contour that passes through an specific point?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I want to plot a curve given by $$f(x,y)\equiv y-y^3+3yx^2=0,$$ that passes through $(0,0)$ and $f(x,y) \to + \infty$ as $|x|,|y| \to \infty$. I thought of using ContourPlot to do so but when I use ContourPlot[y-y^3+3yx^2==0,{x,x_min,x_max},{y,y_min,y_max}], there are three other curves in addition to the one I want. How can I get only the one that is desired? Is there any other function that can give me the four parametric solutions to $y(u)-y(u)^3+3\, y(u)\, x(u)^2=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also post-process the `ContourPlot` output to remove the lines that do not contain `{0,0}`:

```
Normal[ContourPlot[y - y^3 + 3*y*x^2 == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]] /. 
   l_Line /; Not[RegionMember[l, {0, 0}]] :> Nothing
```

[image]

Comment: Just learnt about Nothing! Cool.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation has a trivial solution `y=0 at any x`. Its plot is a straight line along the `x` axis. This one passes through the point `(0,0)`. In addition to that try the following:

```
eq = y - y^3 + 3*y*x^2 == 0;
sl = Solve[eq, x]

(* {{x -> -(Sqrt[-1 + y^2]/Sqrt[3])}, {x -> Sqrt[-1 + y^2]/Sqrt[3]}} *)
```

Then one makes a parametric plot:

```
ParametricPlot[{{sl[[1, 1, 2]], y}, {sl[[2, 1, 2]], y}}, {y, -10, 10},
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

returning the following:

[image]

where two colors correspond to the two above solutions. As the result, either the solution passes through the point `(0,0)`, but `f(x,y)` stays indeterminate in infinity, or the solution does not pass through this point, but then `f(x,y)` turn into infinity at large `x` and `y`.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

ContourPlot finds three solutions

```
ContourPlot[y - y^3 + 3*y*x^2 == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},FrameLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

one of them is the solution you are looking for!

select the "right" curve:

```
cond = Reduce[ y - y^3 + 3*y*x^2 == 0, y] /. Or -> List 
(*{y == 0, y == -Sqrt[1 + 3 x^2], y == Sqrt[1 + 3 x^2]} *)
cond /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}
(*{True, False, False}*)
```

`y == 0` is the solution!